# How to change fonts and axis labels for Chart.js image rendering with QuickChart?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to create graphs using QuickChart and Chart.Js with HTML. I have the following, but want to figure out how to change the font size and font style for all the text. I also want to change the YAxis go to to 10. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers you seek are in the Chart.js documentation.

First, to change the yAxis to go to 10, use `options.scales.yAxes.ticks.suggestedMax` ([chart.js doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html)).

To change font size and style, you can set these values for each component of the graph:

- For the legend, use `options.legend.labels.fontColor/fontStyle/fontFamily` ([chart.js doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html)).
- For the axes, use `options.scales.<axis>.ticks.font*` ([chart.js doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html)).
- For the chart title, use `options.title.font*` ([chart.js doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html)).

Put it all together:

```
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dogs',
      data: [5,6,7,8,9],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'red',
    }, {
      label: 'Reality',
      data: [6,6,5,9,9],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'green',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontStyle: 'bold',
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Dogs v Cats',
      fontSize: 20,
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            suggestedMax: 10,
            beginAtZero: true,
            fontFamily: 'Mono',
          },
        },
      ],
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            fontFamily: 'Serif',
            fontStyle: 'italic',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

[QuickChart link](https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c=%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20%27line%27%2C%0A%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%27January%27%2C%20%27February%27%2C%20%27March%27%2C%20%27April%27%2C%20%27May%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Dogs%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fill%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20borderColor%3A%20%27red%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Reality%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B6%2C6%2C5%2C9%2C9%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fill%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20borderColor%3A%20%27green%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20options%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20legend%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20position%3A%20%27bottom%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontSize%3A%2020%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontStyle%3A%20%27bold%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%27Dogs%20v%20Cats%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fontSize%3A%2020%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20scales%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20yAxes%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ticks%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20suggestedMax%3A%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20beginAtZero%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontFamily%3A%20%27Mono%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xAxes%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ticks%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontFamily%3A%20%27Serif%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontStyle%3A%20%27italic%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)

[image: QuickChart custom fonts]

Comment: Hi, so the issue here is that I'm using Quickchart to render the chart as an image, so the formatting seems to be different. Do you know how I would do it within a url?

<img src="https://quickchart.io/chart?width=300&height=200&c={type:'line',data:{labels:['January','February', 'March','April', 'May'], datasets:[{label:'Dogs', data: [5,6,7,8,9], fill:false,borderColor:'red'},{label:'Reality', data:[6,6,5,9,9], fill:false,borderColor:'green'}]},options:{title:{display:true,text:'Dogs v. Cats',fontSize:10},legend:{position:'bottom',}}}" />

Comment: Yep, see the URL in the "QuickChart link" in my post below the code/above the image.  Just pack that JSON object into the URL (you might have to URL encode it)

Comment: Or paste the JSON into the QuickChart sandbox and it will show you the URL/you can click it and copy the link https://quickchart.io/sandbox/